# One bulb doesnt work in fan

Tags: electrical

Recently my bulbs im my fan I decided to replace with new bulbs. All three bulbs were ok and have always worked and when i pulled them out one of them kind of flickered off then back on then completly off again. I got new bulbs and put them in now that one that flickered even with a new bulb doesnt work.

I tried the same old bulb same issue. What could cause one of these bulbs or sockets to no longer work. Do I need to replace entire fan unit?

Please note all three sockets look split so dont let the picture fool ya.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Shut off the circuit breaker and lift the hot contact tab a little so that it makes better connection with the bulb.

[image: arrow pointing to hot contact tab inside light bulb socket]

If this doesn't work then you could try taking the unit apart and checking for loose wires but that's obviously dependent on your skill level.

---

Overall, I don't think you've done enough troubleshooting yet.

Have you tried testing the "bad" bulb in a good socket? Have you tried testing a "good" bulb in the bad socket?

Comment: Yes i did the obvious of testing the bulb the bulb is brand new and ive tried many of them not just one. I did test the bulb on the working ones and it works fine. I didnt post just to post I did try the obvious next time ill mention every single detail.

Comment: Still doesnt work even with the hot contact tab. Im not too good with taking it apart so I will live with one bad bulb. Thanks anyways

Comment: @john Sounds good. Replacing the whole unit is also an option. At minimum I would take it down and check the back side for any signs of electrical arc. If that too is difficult then I hope that lamp is on an AFCI breaker.